# PHP do-while loop filesize check and stop

Tags: php

So the problem is I'm having is looping to check the file size, for example a file A.txt is 10 bytes and with other php scripts A.txt changes to 20bytes so when the A.txt file is changed I want the iteration to stop.

```
<?php

$i = 1;
$a = filesize("A.txt");
do {
    $c = filesize("A.txt");
    if ($a >= $c) {

    } else {
        echo file_get_contents('chat.log');
        $i++;
    }
} while ($i <= 2);

?>
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: What's your problem with posting your code here?

Comment: Please post the relevant code on your question.

Comment: The only issue I see is that you're not clearing the stat cache. When funcitons such as filesize are called, PHP will cache the result so subsequent calls will always return the same number. Put [`clearstatcache();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) within your loop.

Comment: @Philipp .. actually the code does't work when i try to open that code and change file A.txt in same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to implement *long-polling* for a chat application.

This approach could lead you to lose some chat messages being delivered. And this is not very scalable.

I would suggest you to receive the previously known file size via a GET parameter, and check if the file size is larger than that.

Then I would suggest you to use fopen to open the file and read from the previous pointer (GET parameter) to the end of file, than reading the whole file every time.

you may also want to clearstatcache before each filesize, and add a usleep(100); inside the while loop.

Comment: i will try to use clearstatcache and usleep, actually you right i want to create chat application .. and is combine with my vb.net app so i must do this way to create chat application :)

Comment: Search Google for "php long-polling" to find more techniques for what you are looking for.